# What is the default space between lines in latex?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I'm trying to make all my document with a default layout. So, to make the space between itens in a list, I'd like to know what is the default space between lines in latex in a text (1pt, 1.5em etc)?

If it depends on the font size, my document is a 11pt font size one.

Comment: It is stored in the length `\baselineskip`.  To see what exactly it is, put `\the\baselineskip` in your document and its value will be output.  The value could change, depending on what document class and font you are loading.  For the simple `11pt` value of `article` class with no modifications, the value of `\the\baselineskip` is `13.6pt`.

Comment: I should clarify that `\baselineskip` is not the gap between lines, but rather the default distance between the baselines of two successive lines.

Comment: to add to what @StevenB.Segletes says, a vertical distance (including `\baselineskip`) shouldn't be expressed in `em` units -- that's for horizontal distances.  a more appropriate vertical  unit is `ex`, but that may be hard to use as it may vary wildly between font designs.  an actual physical unit is generally easier to manage.